# Conditional shortcut if and IIF

Tags: vb.net

Why is it not working:

```
data.params("@LocationId", SqlDbType.Int, if(ePLService.tblLocations.LocationId = -1, Nothing, ePLService.tblLocations.LocationId))
```

And this works correctly:

```
data.params("@LocationId", SqlDbType.Int, IIf(ePLService.tblLocations.LocationId = -1, Nothing, ePLService.tblLocations.LocationId))
```

This condition is met:

```
ePLService.tblLocations.LocationId = -1
```

It should insert NULL and it has a problem with it in the first case

Comment: What is the type of `ePLService.tblLocations.LocationId`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton `Public Property LocationId As Integer`

Comment: And what is the problem? Is there some error message, or perhaps an unexpected result? I suspect that using `CType(Nothing, Integer)` instead of `Nothing` will fix it, as both the true and false parts of the `If` then look like they have the type Integer.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by *not working*. In the first example you have `if` which isn't valid in `vb.net`... It's `If` in `vb.net`.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but if you are trying to store `null` in the database, using `Nothing` won't work.  It'll insert a `0` or cause an exception, depending on the situation.  To insert `null`, use `DbNull.Value`.

Comment: @DevNet Does the method `data.params()` do something specific if the third parameter is Nothing?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Depending on the goal, it might be preferable to cast to `Integer?` instead of `Integer`.  Casting `Nothing` to `Integer` is just going to give you 0.

Comment: @Craig That sounds like a much better idea to me.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is type inference. The `If()` operator will infer the type based on the operands, while the `IIf()` function will not.

For this specific code, then, `If()` will infer an `Integer` type and return a `Nothing` integer. *But Nothing is not the same as NULL when applied to value types like integers!* What you end up with is the value `0`.

On the other hand, `IIF()` always uses the `Object` type. When you return the `Nothing` object, you are actually returning `null` (note: this is still not the same thing as a `DBNull`). As for when the condition fails and you actually have a value, .Net must [box the integer as an object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing), which can cost performance and type safety (though you're probably okay in this specific situation).

Finally, note the difference between "operator" and "function" from my first paragraph. That is intentional, and results in another observable difference between them. As a function, all the arguments to `IIf()` must be resolved *before* it can actually be called. This means the `PLService.tblLocations.LocationId` expression must be evaluated, even when it won't be used. Again, for this specific code you're likely okay, but in many situations this can result in things like unexpected NullReference exceptions. As an operator, `If()` does not have this limitation.